# Implementing a Queue

Tags: c#, arrays, queue

Is there a way to implement a queue but have multiple items under each entry
i.e. someone joins a queue with the following characteristics: ID, # days, etc.
I've included my code below... but basically I'd like to be able to add multiple charactertistics to one entry in  a queue

```
        int numberArrivals;
        Random random = new Random();
        numberArrivals = random.Next(0, 3); 
        Queue LineQueue = new Queue();

        int day =0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberArrivals; i++)
        {
            int severity = random.Next(1, 6);
            LineQueue.Enqueue(severity, #days, etc.); <--
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you make a class that associates that data and make a queue of those; or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics!

Write a class to store your data:

```
public class Entry
{
    public int Severity { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

And use a generic queue:

```
var queue = new Queue<Entry>();
queue.Enqueue( new Entry() { Severity = 7, Days = 3 } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are looking for is a class that represents your object. Then have a `Queue<YourClass>` instead of non-generic `Queue`